# Mirror modifyer not mirroring the movement of an object

Tags: mirror

to be specific im creating a character, i mirrored the left eyeball and i grab it and  move towards the centre which suppose to make the two eyeball closer , but what what happend instead is the right eyeball moved outside the skull. When i move the other objects, such as eyebrow, it is mirroring the movement. Dont know why just the eyeball is moving wrongly, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're in object mode. Check that. It should get closer if you move the eyeball in edit mode.

Comment: Oh yeah!! Thank you very much, saved my life, thought i was making some mistakes